# Using .NET language pack for DataAnnotations localization, how to add satellite assembly to project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, localization

I have a MVC app using [MVC Validation](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/adding-validation) and would like to use the localized messages for validation errors Microsoft has in their [.NET Language Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30667). The problem is I can't install the language pack on the destination server since it's Azure, but have manually extracted *System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Resources.dll* from the language pack. Is there someway I can add this satellite assembly to my project?

Since satellite assemblies by default should be located relative to it's main assembly (I'm not sure if other locations are supported) I was wondering if anything from [codeBase or probing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15hyw9x3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) could help? For example by copying *System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll* to the output bin folder and overcoming the [default search order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yx7xezcf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which I think favours GAC over application folder, or by allowing satellite assemblies to be found under application folder even though main dll is located somewhere else.

Comment: did you figure out how to do this ?

Comment: If you want language packs to be added to Azure Web Apps, please vote for this request : http://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps-formerly-websites/suggestions/9854277-provide-net-language-packs-on-web-apps

Comment: @bob Thanks for link. I ended up using dotPeek and copied the validation messages I was using to my project.

Comment: OK thank you for your feedback. Too bad Azure has still no language pack...